# Restrict the user access in multi site for non-assigned blogs

Tags: multisite, user-access, content-restriction

What is the better way to restrict a user of any role being logging into a blog of wordpress multisite network if he/she is not assigned to that particular blog as a user even though he is an administrator of another blog in that network. I hope it can be done using `get_blogs_of_user( $user );` function where `$user` is the username of person who trying to login.

**EDIT:** My code as follows.

```
 $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember'] = true;

 $user_signon = wp_signon($info, false);
    if (is_wp_error($user_signon)) {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin' => false, 'message' => __('Invalid Credentials.')));
    } else {
    $get_blogs = get_blogs_of_user(get_user_by('login',$info['user_login'])->ID);
    $is_has_access = array_search(get_current_blog_id(), array_column($get_blogs, 'userblog_id'));
    if (!$is_has_access) {
         wp_logout();
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin' => false, 'message' => __('You have no permission to access.')));
    } else {
            echo json_encode(array('loggedin' => true, 'message' => __('Login successful')));
       }
    }
```

Is there any better ways?

Comment: A user can be an administrator on Site A and yet have no access to Site B (ie, she'd have the same access to Site B as any non-logged-in user visiting Site B). This is already part of Multisite.

Comment: That is wanted. But in my install of multisite, if user is admin of site A, then he can login to site B. But my aim is to restrict his login to site B

Comment: Well, he can log in by going to site B, but he won't be able to *do* anything there. IIRC, he'll be given a list of links to sites where he *can* do things. You're trying to deny him the ability to log in at site B?

Comment: Yes... I don't want the user to login to site B

Answer (score 1):

[`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) is a [pluggable function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions), which means you can override its functionality. That's probably where I'd start.

Something like this may do what you're looking for. This is untested code and comes with no warranties of any kind.

```
function is_user_logged_in() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
    $allowed = false;
    $blogs_of_user = get_blogs_of_user( $user->ID );
    foreach( $blogs_of_user as $blog ) {
        if( $blog->userblog_id == $current_blog_id ) {
            $allowed = true;
        }
    }

    if( ! $allowed ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $user->exists();
```

}

### References

- [Pluggable Functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions)
- [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)
- [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/)
- [`get_current_blog_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_blog_id/)
- [`get_blogs_of_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blogs_of_user/)